# Why did my Docker Container did not work when the container UID is missing on the host?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have created a docker image for running a wildfly server. In the docker image I define a separate user called 'imixs'. This user is running the service (wildfly server) inside the container.

As I have seen in several examples I created my service user with UID 1000.

```
RUN groupadd -r imixs -g 1000 && useradd -u 1000 -r -g imixs -m -d /home/imixs -s /sbin/nologin -c "imixs user" imixs && \
    chmod 755 /opt
```

Now I have the situation, that on a Host, where this UID is missing, the container can not be executed correctly, because the service (wildfly) claims about missing write permissions.

1. Is it recommended to start the container in this case with the option -u to run the container with a different user from the host system?

   docker run ... -u myuser ....
2. How can I tell docker-compose to run the containers with a different user from the host system?
3. Is it in general recommended to create images with users others then root?

My dokerfile can be seen here: https://hub.docker.com/r/imixs/wildfly/~/dockerfile/

Comment: Please include your full run command, particularly any volume mounts, along with a long listing of those folders on your host system, and the exact error message you are seeing.

Comment: It looks that upgrading to actual docker version solved this probelm

Answer (score 0):

I think I must withdraw my own question. I solved this behavior after upgrading from docker version 1.6 to the current release 1.13.0 and upgrading docker-compose form 1.5 to 1.10.0.
Maybe there was something wrong in general with my old installation and reinstalling fixed this problem. 
In any case I can confirm that there is no read/write permission issue if the container runs a service with a non-privileged-user, not defined by the host system.

To answer my own questions:

1. Yes it is recommended to run services in a container with a non-privileged-user other than root (uid 0)
2. I still did not know if docker-compose can change the user to be used to  run a specific container
3. No it is not recommended to create images running with root user